# Reading attribute from shapefile using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, point, attribute-table, coordinates

Currently I am making a script that allows the user to draw a line, the line is then created into end points with lat/long available.

From this lat/long, I have to run some math equations to figure out where the next coordinates should be.
I have gotten it to create the points based on a line, calculate the bearing, and used ArcPy to place the next point into the shapefile using my math equation as a test.

I am using Arcmap 10.4 for testing. I have access to Pro and 10.7, but I am using 10.4 just to learn.

My question is how do I read the attributes of a file so that I can use the X/Y of a point to run my equations on?

I have (light) experience using Pandas, working with CSV's etc just very new to ArcPy. Below is a list of what I am doing to make it easy.

1. Create line. Use COGO to add bearing.
2. Create points from lines.
3. Read attribute table. Read X/Y.  (This is what I need help with).
4. Run equation on X/Y to get the next 4 points.
5. Add points to point shapefile.

When I have it figured out I can provide an update to share the code with for future use.

Comment: You could just use the [make XY event layer tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) which makes an in-memory layer object which you can either process directly or save out to a permanent dataset which you process (e.g. add new fields to).

Comment: I will take a look at using this option. That sounds like it would be useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [da.SearchCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm):

> SearchCursor establishes read-only access to the records returned from
> a feature class or table.

With the SHAPE@XY token:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\data.gdb\featureclass'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, 'SHAPE@XY') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        x, y = row[0]
```

[image]